# mongodb correct list order in complex aggregation with $unwind, $lookup and $group

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I have an issue auto-dereferencing sub-objects using aggregate and keep list order doing this. First: my data model. Let's break it down to two collections (and I use simplified ids to make it easier to understand):

meeting:

```
{
    'id': '1',
    'some': 'abc',
    'data': 'def',
    'agendaItem': [
        ObjectId('2'),
        ObjectId('3')
    ]
}
```

agenda_item:

```
{
    'id': ObjectId('2'),
    'some': 'ghi',
    'data': 'jkl'
},
{
    'id': ObjectId('3'),
    'some': 'mno',
    'data': 'pqr'
}
```

The result of my single(!) query should be like this:

```
{
    'id': ObjectId('1'),
    'some': 'abc',
    'data': 'def',
    'agenda_items': [
        {
            'id': ObjectId('2'),
            'some': 'ghi',
            'data': 'jkl'
        },
        {
            'id': ObjectId('3'),
            'some': 'mno',
            'data': 'pqr'
        }
    ]
}
```

The important part is that the list of agenda_items should stay in the same order, id 2 has to be on the top.

At the moment, I use a aggregate with unwind, lookup and group to do such a query:

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True,
            'path': '$agendaItem'
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'agenda_item',
            'as': 'agendaItem',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'localField': 'agendaItem'
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True,
            'path': '$agendaItem'
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            'agendaItem': {
            '$addToSet': '$agendaItem'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This gives me the result I want - with one exception: the list is completely mixed up, which means in this example ObjectId('3') is before ObjectId('2').

Using addFields like in this blog post by MongoDb: http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/using-34-aggregation-to-return-documents-in-same-order-as-in-expression is somehow the solution, but I have no real idea how to put it into the $unwind + $lookup chain. Can you help me? Or is my strategy completely wrong?

Background in German btw: https://oparl.org/spezifikation/online-ansicht/ and https://mirror.oparl.org/body/5a3d010888dbe04745b24e0a/meeting

Comment: Why are you using addToSet ? `$addToSet` is not guaranteed to maintain the order. Use `$push` and add  a `$sort` stage before the `$group` stage for stable ordering. So last two stages should be `{$sort:{"agendaItem.id":1}}, {
        '$group': {'_id':'$id',
            'agendaItem': {
            '$push': '$agendaItem'
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: I suppose because I still have my issues to understand the aggregation framework, so I just overlooked the issue with `addToSet`. But this works great for existing values.
So the follow up issue: I don't want to have it ordered by id, instead exacly in order how it is saved in MongoDB list. I suppose the solution is `$addField`, but I have no clue where to add it. Can you give me a hint there?

Comment: I'm guessing you are on 3.4 because you mentioned `$addFields`.Just don't `$unwind` and `$group` ( Its not needed in 3.4 ). Try just this and no other stages `db.col.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'agenda_item',
            'as': 'agendaItem',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'localField': 'agendaItem'
        }
    }
])`

Comment: `$addField` was something I googled searching for a solution. It's a new project, so I can choose any MongoDB version I want. But I created the code snippet when MongoDB 3.2 was the current version for another project.
And: your hint works great. So this got "much" easier the last versions, and I just did not check if simplification would do the job now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The solution suggested by @user2683814 does not work, unfortunately. The `$lookup` stage does lookup all items of the array and outputs an array if `localField` is an array. However, it's not guaranteed the resulting field will be output in the same order as the input array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate $lookup does not return elements original array order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033804/aggregate-lookup-does-not-return-elements-original-array-order)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem to resolve.

The solution can be found here:
[Aggregate $lookup does not return elements original array order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033804/aggregate-lookup-does-not-return-elements-original-array-order)