# Aggregate $lookup does not return elements original array order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The query returns the order in which elements are placed in their collection, ignoring the order of the initial array. This affects the function of our system. Is there any extra command to put it in the correct order? Is there any workaround available?

Here follows a simple example:

**Collection1 Document**

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5c781752176c512f180048e3"),
  "Name":"Pedro",
  "Classes":[
    {"ID": ObjectId("5c7af2b2f6f6e47c9060d7ce") },
    {"ID": ObjectId("5c7af2bcf6f6e47c9060d7cf") },
    {"ID": ObjectId("5c7af2aaf6f6e47c9060d7cd") }
  ]
}
```

**Collection2 Documents**

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5c7af2aaf6f6e47c9060d7cd"),
  "variable1":"A"
},

{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c7af2b2f6f6e47c9060d7ce"),
  "variable1":"B"
},

{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c7af2bcf6f6e47c9060d7cf"),
  "variable1":"C"
}
```

**The query:**

```
aggregate(
  pipeline = '[
  {"$match": {"_id": {"$oid": "5c781752176c512f180048e3"}}},
  {"$lookup": {"from": "collection2", "localField": "Classes.ID", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "Collection2_doc"}}
  ]'
)
```

Returns:

**Result's order:**

```
[
    {
      "_id":ObjectId("5c7af2aaf6f6e47c9060d7cd"),
      "variable1":"A"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5c7af2b2f6f6e47c9060d7ce"),
      "variable1":"B"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5c7af2bcf6f6e47c9060d7cf"),
      "variable1":"C"
    }
]
```

**Expected order (first document array order):**

```
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5c7af2b2f6f6e47c9060d7ce"),
      "variable1":"B"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5c7af2bcf6f6e47c9060d7cf"),
      "variable1":"C"
    },
    {
      "_id":ObjectId("5c7af2aaf6f6e47c9060d7cd"),
      "variable1":"A"
    }
]
```

Are there any extra command ex. `$sort` that could be used to return it respecting the original arrays order?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is "by design" of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) implementation. What *actually* happens *"under the hood"* is MongoDB *internall* converts the arguments in the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to the new *expressive* format using [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/). Even in versions prior to when this *expressive* form was implemented, the internal mechanics for an *"array of values"* was really much the same.

The solution here is to maintain a copy of the original array as a reference for reordering the *"joined"* items:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5c781752176c512f180048e3") }},
  {"$lookup": {
    "from": "collection2",
    "let": { "classIds": "$Classes.ID" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$classIds" ] }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "sort": {
          "$indexOfArray": [ "$$classIds", "$_id" ]
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "sort": 1 } },
      { "$addFields": { "sort": "$$REMOVE" }}
    ],
    "as": "results"
  }}
])
```

Or by the legacy [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) usage:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId("5c781752176c512f180048e3") }},
  {"$lookup": {
    "from": "collection2",
    "localField": "Classes.ID",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "results"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$results" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "sort": {
      "$indexOfArray": [ "$Classes.ID", "$results._id" ]
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "sort": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "Name": { "$first": "$Name" },
    "Classes": { "$first": "$Classes" },
    "results": { "$push": "$results" }
  }}
])
```

Both variants produce the same output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c781752176c512f180048e3"),
        "Name" : "Pedro",
        "Classes" : [
                {
                        "ID" : ObjectId("5c7af2b2f6f6e47c9060d7ce")
                },
                {
                        "ID" : ObjectId("5c7af2bcf6f6e47c9060d7cf")
                },
                {
                        "ID" : ObjectId("5c7af2aaf6f6e47c9060d7cd")
                }
        ],
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7af2b2f6f6e47c9060d7ce"),
                        "variable1" : "B"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7af2bcf6f6e47c9060d7cf"),
                        "variable1" : "C"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c7af2aaf6f6e47c9060d7cd"),
                        "variable1" : "A"
                }
        ]
}
```

The general concept being to use [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) in comparison with the `_id` value from the *"joined"* content to find it's *"index"* position in the original source array from `"$Classes.ID"`. The different [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax variants have different approaches to how you access this *copy* and how you basically reconstruct.

The [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) of course sets the order of actual documents, either being *inside the pipeline processing* for the expressive form, or via the exposed documents of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Where you used [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) you would then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) back to the original document form.

> **NOTE**: The usage examples here depend on MongoDB 3.4 for the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) at least and the [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#conditionally-exclude-fields) aligns with MongoDB 3.6 as would the *expressive* `$lookup`.
>
> There are other approaches to re-ordering the array for prior releases, but these are demonstrated in more detail on [Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22797768/2313887). Realistically the bare minimum you should presently be running as a production MongoDB version is the 3.4 release.
>
> See [**Support Policy**](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy) under **MongoDB Server** for the full details of supported releases and end dates.

Comment: This answer is 100% wrong. No conversion of $lookup to $expr and $in happens.  It's just equivalent to a regular find with $in.   And this is not a great workaround - it's easier to not overwrite the original array (to preserve order) and then merge it with the returned from $lookup array of documents.  That also caters to the array not matching all the elements in the other collection.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky could you provide an answer with the above example?

Comment: Does the `$match` in the lookup pipeline do anything in your first example? The array should only contain matching array entries anyway, right?