# How to get list of id of all ROOT documents to pass to $lookup pipeline MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have 2 collections:

`users` collection:

```py
{
    "_id": "1234141341"
    "name": "David",
    "is_active": True,
    "age": 20
}
```

`locations` collection:

```py
{
    "owner": "1234141341"
    "type": "Point"
    "coordinates": [ 105.843111, 21.045752 ]
}
```

I want to join `users` collection with `locations` collection. My query:

```py
db.collection.aggregrate(
    {
        "$match": {
            "is_active": True,
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "locations",
            "as": "location",
            "let": {"user_id": "$_id", "list_user_id": "the expression to get list of user id after $match stage"},
            "pipeline": [
                { 
                    "$geoNear": {
                        "near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 105.843111, 21.045752 ]},
                        "distanceField": "distance",
                        "query": {
                            // "owner": {"$in": "$$list_user_id"}      // <---- filter location that belong filtered user here
                        },
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$redact": {
                        "$cond": {
                            "if": {"$lte": ["$distance", 10000000000]},
                            "then": "$$KEEP",
                            "else": "$$PRUNE",
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {"$eq": ["$owner", "$$user_id"]},
                    },
                },
            ],
        }
    }
)
```

For optimize this aggregrate query, I want to get list of user id after stage `$match`, then pass this list of user id to stage `$geoNear` of `$lookup` for filter location that belong to filtered users. So this `$geoNear` stage will not calculate all locations. I have read mongo document, also read questions in this site, but I can not find out the answer. Any idea about this is appreciated, thanks

Comment: what is that `$$list_user_id`? Can you just do `query: { owner: $$user_id}`

Comment: @chakwok, `$$list_user_id` is what I mentioned above, but I don't know how to get this `list_user_id`. I have commented this line, it is just describe my idea. If using `query: { owner: $$user_id}` the `$geoNear` only calculate distance for only one user, but I want calculate distance for all filtered user after `$match` stage

Comment: Why do you need `$$list_user_id` if you are going to match with `$$user_id` anyways?

Comment: Although this does not answer you question, but I guess `"$geoNear": { ... "query": { "$expr": { $eq: ['$owner', '$$user_id'] } } }` would get what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you want to do a filter in the collection being looked up you do:

```
{"$match": {
 "$expr": { "$in": [ "$owner", "$$user_id" ] }
}}
```

You can either add a `$match` stage at the beginning or I believe you can put the whole `$expr` expression into the query.

Comment: As mongodb document, `$geoNear` must be the first stage of pipeline, so I can not use `$match` before `$geoNear` in `pipeline` of `$lookup`.

Comment: How about putting the `$expr` in the `$geoNear.query`?

Comment: I have edited my query a litle bit for make clearly my idea. I can put `$expr` into `geoNear.query`. I also intend to do that. But what make me stuck here is that how can i get list of user id after `$match` stage ?

Comment: I think `$$userId` is already the array you are referring to? The answer has an explanation.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033804/aggregate-lookup-does-not-return-elements-original-array-order

Comment: The explanation can not applied for me. Let's disscuss again. After `$match: { is_active: True}` I will get a list of user, right ? I will use this list filtered user to do `$lookup` with `locations` collection. In `$lookup.let`,  I defined a variable named `user_id=_id` is user id of current input document. But now I also want to define a variable 'list_user_id` that contain a list of  user'id of all input document. How can I do that?

Comment: @PhùngXuânAnh  I understand what you meant. What I am saying is that `$$userId` you defined in `$lookup.let`  is not "the userId of current input document". Instead, it is the "list of userId of all input document". 
Take a look at mongodb document, `$in` takes two arguments, `{ $in: [ <expression>, <array expression> ] }`, so the `$$user_id` is an array, but not a userId

Comment: Ah, I know that, I also checked, `$$user_id` is just an id of an user. So I need to get list of all user id and assigne to variable `list_user_id`. Then I can do ` {"$match": {
 "$expr": { "$in": [ "$owner", "$$list_user_id" ] }
}}` as you said above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214404/discussion-between-phung-xuan-anh-and-chakwok).

Comment: @PhùngXuânAnh Sorry, I totally misread your question. Not sure if it's the most straight forward solution, but it does the optimization you wanted. However, if you need the information from `users` you many need to lookup again... https://mongoplayground.net/p/WZYNDVhmdaO

Comment: Sr for answer late, as your suggest, I am trying to use variable  `$$userIds` inside `geoNear.query` instead of `$match`, like this: `$geoNear.query("owner": {$in: $$userIds})` but not successfully. It raise error: `$in needs an array`

Comment: @PhùngXuânAnh did you add the `$group` stage before the lookup as I did in the mongoplayground? I tested the query and it works fine

Comment: Please review, My code here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OXN5zayRzqe